# about locations of programs

Tags: software-installation

where do i find the icons for a program that i wish to run...meaning i dont know where anything is and i dont know how to start say my dvd player...im obviously learning the os and im liking it alot but as with a windows os, the icons for any application that i want to use are either installed by default or i know where to find them...in this case with Ubuntu it installs the applications fine but it leaves no viewable icons for me and i dont know where to look to find them if i want to start up a app,and not knowing the command line at all, im kinda stuck not knowin where to find these things...im liking ubuntu alot, so im enjoying the learning process for the new os i just need a little assistance in learning this part of it...any help is appreciated and i thank u for listening...

Answer (score 0):

You can find most of the application by pressing:

```
Super + A
```

Where "Super" is the key with the Windows logo on it (we don't like to call it the Windows key, as you'll see in most of the tutorials). There, you can type the name of the application you're searching for, or just scroll down and search for it.

If you just press Super, it'll show you a mix of applications, files and folders you've recently used. Super + F will take you to files and folders.

Here's an screenshot:

[image]

If you still prefer a more classic menú, like the one in Windows XP or 7, with categories etc, you can install classicmenu-indicator with this three commands.

Open a terminal (use the Super key and type gnome-terminal) and then type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

When it's done, just start classicmenu-indicator by searching for it in the same dash, or if you're still in the terminal type:

```
classicmenu-indicator
```

You'll see a more intuitive menu appear on the top right of your screen. Browse it and if you like it, you can set it in the options so it auto-launch when you log in.

Might I add if there's a program you run very often, you can right click on its icon on the left bar and check "lock it to the launcher" or "pin to the launcher" so it'll stay there for a quicker access (not sure what the exact words are because I'm using the Catalan translation, but I'm sure you'll find the option).

Comment: that was exactly the info i needed to get things goin, now i know that the keyboard shortcuts i already know will probably work with this os...darent u were most helpful and i graciously thank you